# ActivePerl doesn’t output fatals to browser

Tags: perl, iis, iis-7, activeperl

I'm using the following code to test the outputting of fatal errors to the browser:

```
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

die "test";
```

I am expecting to see some error in the browser, but there isn't any, I just get a regular 500 response. I forgot that I had custom error pages on for remote requests, and I now get `Script failed to send data.`.

Also:

```
> perl -w index.pl
Status: 500
Content-type: text/html

<h1>Software error:</h1>
<pre>test at index.pl line 4.</pre>
<p>
For help, please send mail to this site's webmaster, giving this error message and the time and date of the error.

</p>
[Mon Feb  8 18:29:52 2010] index.pl: test at index.pl line 4.
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to test with something syntactically valid?

Comment: If I replace the print with `print "test";` it works fine, I want to test outputting errors to the browser now.

Comment: And you expect syntax errors that kill Perl before your modules are even loaded to be somehow outputted? Try generating a fatal runtime error and see if that works.

Comment: You're right. However, changing the 'print' to 'die' doesn't help much, I still get a 500.

Comment: You haven't gone through my Perl CGI troubleshooting guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165022/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-perl-cgi-script

Comment: I updated my question (I disabled custom error pages).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try printing a couple of new lines before anything. That signals the end of HTTP headers to the server as the ['CGI standard'](http://hoohoo.ncsa.illinois.edu/cgi/primer.html) says. Or you may be able to use something like this: (as copied from the [Carp man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI/Carp.html)):

```
use CGI::Carp qw(set_die_handler);
BEGIN {
   sub handle_errors {
      my $msg = shift;
      print "content-type: text/html\n\n";
      print "<h1>Oh gosh</h1>";
      print "<p>Got an error: $msg</p>";
  }
  set_die_handler(\&handle_errors);
}
```

If that doesn't work here are a few more tricks:

```
#!perl
BEGIN { $| = 1; print "\n\n" }
open STDERR, ">&STDOUT";
```

..And a few more tricks [in this Perl Journal article](http://www.foo.be/docs/tpj/issues/vol3_1/tpj0301-0006.html).

Comment: This still just returns a 500.

Comment: What about putting this at the top of your cgi file: BEGIN { $| = 1; print "\n\n" }

Comment: That gives me a 200, but it doesn't print the `die`.

Comment: .. and add a stderr redirect. see above.

Comment: I think I'm going to use this workaround. Works perfect so far!