# Why doesn't my Perl CGI program work on Windows?

Tags: perl, xampp

I have written following  in `index.pl` which is the `C:\xampp\htdocs\perl` folder:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "<html>";
print "<h2>PERL IT!</h2>";
print "this is some text that should get displyed in browser";
print "</html>";
```

When I browse to `http://localhost:88/perl/` the above HTML doesn't get displayed (I have tried in IE FF and chrome).

What would be the reason?

I have `xampp` and `apache2.2` installed on this Windows XP system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's because you didn't put your text between `<body>` tags. Also you have to specify the content type as `text/html`.

Try this:

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"; 
print "<html>";
print "<h2>PERL IT!</h2>";
print "<body>";
print "this is some text that should get displyed in browser";
print "</body>";
print "</html>";
```

Also, from the link rics gave,

```
Perl:
Executable: \xampp\htdocs and \xampp\cgi-bin
Allowed endings: .pl
```

so you should be accessing your script like:
`http://localhost/cgi-bin/index.pl`

Comment: the edited code you gave how to use it?   


Perl:
Executable: \xampp\htdocs and \xampp\cgi-bin
Allowed endings: .pl

Comment: The above means that your html should go under htdocs and all perl scripts should be place under cgi-bin folder

Answer (score 4):

See also [How do I troubleshoot my Perl CGI Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165022/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-perl-cgi-script).

Your problem was due to the fact that your script did not send the appropriate headers.

A valid [HTTP response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6) consists of two sections: Headers and body.

You should make sure that you use a proper CGI processing module. [CGI.pm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI) is the *de facto* standard. However, it has a lot of historical baggage and [CGI::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI::Simple) provides a cleaner alternative.

Using one of those modules, your script would have been:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use CGI::Simple;

my $cgi = CGI::Simple->new;

print $cgi->header, <<HTML;
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Perl CGI Script</h1>
<p>this is some text that should get displyed in browser</p>
</body>
</html>
HTML
```

Keep in mind that [print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) has no problem with multiple arguments. There is no reason to learn to program like it's 1999.

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing.

- Have you started the `apache` server?
- Is `88` the correct port for reaching your `apache`?

You may also try `http://localhost:88/perl/index.pl` (so adding the script name to the correct address).

Check [this documentation](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) for help.

Comment: @rics thanks for reply ,
apache is on (started)when i run this ,also 88 is right port cause other project i created in php works just fine