# Why does my Perl CGI script cause a 500 internal server error?

Tags: perl, cgi

I get a 500 internal server error when I try to run the code below in a web server which supports perl:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use LWP;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent("TestApp/0.1 ");
$ua->env_proxy();

my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => 'http://www.google.com/loc/json');

$req->content_type('application/jsonrequest');
$req->content('{ "cell_towers": [{"location_area_code": "55000", "mobile_network_code": "95", "cell_id": "20491", "mobile_country_code": "404"}], "version": "1.1.0", "request_address": "true"}');

my $res = $ua->request($req);
if ($res->is_success) {
print $res->content,"\n";
} else {
print $res->status_line, "\n";
return undef;
}
```

But there is no error when I run the code below:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);


print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<HTML>\n";
print "<HEAD><TITLE>Hello World!</TITLE></HEAD>\n";
print "<BODY>\n";
print "<H2>Hello World!</H2> <br /> \n";

foreach $key (sort keys(%ENV)) {
print "$key = $ENV{$key}<p>" ;
}
print "</BODY>\n";
print "</HTML>\n";
```

So I think there is some problem with my code. When I run the first perl script in my local machine with the -wc command, it says that the syntax is OK. Help me please.

Comment: When you have trouble with a Perl CGI script, go through my "Troubleshooting Perl CGI Script": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165022/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-perl-cgi-script

Comment: I don't know whether this helps but I got my perl-cgi script working after I put shebang line `#!C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're running the first script as a CGI script? You need to include the content type:

```
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
```

before any other output (change `text/plain` to `text/html` or whatever is appropriate, of course!)

Answer (score 0):

use what you are using in other script.

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<HTML>\n";
```

Also, Look at [CGI Programming](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_perl/cgiprogramming.html) for writing a healthy script.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're seeing is the "500 Server Error" page, even with `use CGI::Carp qw(FatalsToBrowser)`, then the web server is failing to start your Perl program - it's in the wrong place, `perl` isn't at `/usr/bin/perl`, the directory doesn't have cgi execution enabled, or whatever.

The general rule when you get a 500 error is to look in the web server's error log to see what the actual error message was.

**Edit:** Just re-read the question and realized I was looking at the "working" code rather than the "not working" code.  That changes the list of potential problem points, and the earlier answer that *any* CGI executable *must* return a content-type (even if it returns nothing else) is a likely cause of the problem, but my original take-home message is unaffected:  "500 Internal Server Error" means "*check the server error log*".

Answer (score 0):

## 500 internal server error

may be caused by incorrect permissions:  try **CHMOD 755** to the files/folders you want to execute..