# Perl script wont run; just displays actual code in the browser

Tags: html, perl

I am new to Perl and am having trouble getting my scripts to run properly.  Where am I supposed to put the actual Perl scripts in order for them to run correctly?  I am testing everything out on my lap top and am trying to call a script from a html page and all I get is the actual script (code) itself displayed in my web browser as opposed to the information that the code is designed to produce.  Therefore, I figure I am supposed to put the Perl file somewhere else? Currently I have the Perl script and the HTML file in the same directory. Any help would be greatly appreciated!  See below:

```
 <head>
   <title>Student Web Page</title>
 </head>

 <body>

  <h1>WELCOME! You have reached Kito's Student Web Page</h1>
  <br />
  <p>To run the folloiwing applications, click on the appropriate line:</p>

  <form ACTION="first.pl" METHOD="get">
    <p>
    <input TYPE="submit" VALUE="Step 5 - Perl Environment Variables">
    </p>
  </form>
```

---

```
#!c:\perl\bin\perl.exe -w
use strict;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Environment Variables</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>";

foreach (keys %ENV) {
    print "<BR><FONT COLOR=green>$_</FONT> is set to <FONT COLOR=red>$ENV{$_}</FONT>";
}

print "</BODY></HTML>";
```

Comment: Also, whenever I run the Perl script from the command line it works properly and displays the environmental variables.

Comment: This is a webserver configuration issue. Please provide some information about your webserver type and operating system. Also consider moving it to ServerFault. Note: Your server may have been configured correctly and you just have to name the file correctly (.pl) and put it in the correct directory. Check your webserver config on where Perl-scripts will be executed.

Comment: What Tedd said. Depending on which web server you're running, you usually need to place the file in a specific "scripts" directory (by default `cgi-bin` for Apache) and sometimes name them specifically though the directory is more likely to be an issue.

Comment: You also might want to "use CGI;".  It will make the process of generating the header and the HTML much easier.

Comment: Okay, I switched the file name to .cgi (still doesnt execute in my broswer).  I have IIS 7 and Tomcat downloaded on my lap top which is running Windows 7.  I have been "googling" stuff all day trying to figure this out.  I am sure it is probably really simple, I just have not been able to figure it out yet.  How do I configure my web browser (I use Firefox and have as default Internet Explorer) to run these dang .cgi scripts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I troubleshoot my Perl CGI script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165022/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-perl-cgi-script)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to configure your webserver to execute the CGI file. How this is done depends on the webserver and operating system.

Some examples:
http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/addcgitoapache.shtml

Comment: Checking it out.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3):

Under linux with apache install the mod_cgi module. Under windows with IIS install activestate perl.

Comment: Based on his shebang line, he's most certainly not on Linux :) `#!c:\perl\bin\perl.exe -w`

Comment: @DVK: Yeah, or he is developing the script on win and forgot to change the shebang to match the new environment, which could be a problem as well :)

Comment: @Cyber - while's its remotely possible, I find it highly unlikely that someone with enough skills/experience to develop a script on Windows AND then port it to Linux to not know about cgi-bin... plus, IIRC Windows Apache has the same directory structure.

Comment: Did not pay attention to the shebang ;)