# when testing my perl script shows up as text file and does not run

Tags: html, perl, forms

I am a beginner web programmer and have crated an html form that will run a script. When I open the file off my computer to test (not on a web server) it does not execute the script. It just displays the script in my browser as a text file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807155/perl-script-wont-run-just-displays-actual-code-in-the-browser

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing a CGI, you probably want a server that serves html and is configured to execute the perl CGI.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's because you're opening the file to view it. Run the script from the command line.

Comment: Can i not test it from the .html form that runs it? I have to do it from the terminal?

Comment: Unless it's a script using a web framework (CGI, Catalyst, Dancer, etc) then yes (of course).

Comment: You kind of lost me there...

When running it through the how do i pass arguments through it that it would get from the html form?

Comment: Does the script make use of a Perl web framework such as CGI, Catalyst, or Dancer?  If not, then it should probably be run from the command line anyway.

Comment: Here is my perl script:

http://pastebin.com/h84w538U

Comment: @searayman, if it's a CGI script, you need to run it through a web server in order to test the output in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you remove the thing that executes the script (the web server) from the equation, the script won't get executed.

Comment: @searayman, You didn't ask a question, so I just confirmed what you said.