# How to run perl script on linux server, which is operated by cPanel?

Tags: perl, cpanel, cgi-bin

Can any one please tell me how to run perl script on server.
I uploaded it using FTP. Script does not work by adding `.pl` file in cgi-bin folder. I also tried uploading it with cPanel.

```
BEGIN {
   my $base_module_dir = (-d '/home/username/perl' ?
   '/home/username/perl' : ( getpwuid($>)
   )[7] . '/perl/');
  unshift @INC, map { $base_module_dir . $_ } @INC; }
```

For last option I even tried to add

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

in the beginning of the script.

What else I could try?

Comment: what errors do u see while trying to run the script ?

Comment: cPanel is a red herring. Follow the [classic CGI trouble-shooting instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165022/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-perl-cgi-script).

Comment: cpanel should surely give you an error log for your cgi apps?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need the execute bit set: chmod +x filename.pl