# perl page not read as perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to run this script

> > mail.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html \n\n"; #HTTP HEADER

#CREATE
$email = "pt-desu\@*****-****.com";

#PRINT
print "$email<br />";
```

The file could be accessed via http://mysite.com/p/cgi-bin/mail.pl but when you go there the browser proms to download the file and does not display anything

Comment: I see a server error - page not found. That's more of an server (Apache??) setup problem if it's not executing dirt-simple Perl.

Comment: From the [SO Perl FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=faq): [How can I troubleshoot my Perl CGI script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165022/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-perl-cgi-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your webserver isn't set up to process `*.pl` files as Perl; it's instead just serving them up as plain-text. Consult your webserver's documentation for setting this up.

For Apache, try consulting [this tutorial](http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/addcgitoapache.shtml). The key bits are:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
```

and

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

and

```
Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
```

...in your `httpd.conf` file.