# perl script spits the code but does not excute

Tags: perl

Im trying to excute few perl script but it just spit the code .. 
I know perl script should be in cgi-bin  but my host is www.something.com:8080 which consist of my website (mostly jsp) .. do i have to create another cgi-bin in 8080 !!?

help!!

Comment: all the permission are 755 .. so that shouldnt be a problem.. should it! .. and im pretty sure perl is installed.. (perl -e 'print "Hello, World!\n";') excutes just fine ..

Comment: This is a webserver configuration issue, not a Perl issue, and the solution depends on your webserver. Without knowing anything else, I would try renaming the script so it ends in `.cgi` and making sure it has a valid shebang line at the top (`#!/usr/bin/perl` or whatever).

Comment: i have 2 servers .. one of which is www.something.com  and the perl script work like a charm (placed in cgi-bin) .. the other is in www.something.com:8080 but everytime i try to run those scripts .. its says .. www.something.com:8080/cgi-bin/script.pl not found .. 
any suggestions?

Comment: From the [Stack Overflow Perl FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=faq): [*How can I troubleshoot my Perl CGI script?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165022/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-perl-cgi-script)

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, 80 is the default port for web servers.  8080 is one your system admin set up.  The problems could be:  1) the web server is not configured to run on that port; 2) the server is not running on that port; 3) the server is not configured to handle CGIs on that port.

Comment: how can i have the server configured to handle cgi from that port?