# Internal Server Error when the perl code run

Tags: perl

I am getting the internal server error when run the perl script.I put the file into the cgi-bin folder and set the permission 755. please let me know the How can I resolve this?

There are two files in cgi-bin folder.One is perldigger.cgi. It is working fine its url is http://mts.marketsignalsoftware.com/cgi-bin/perldigger.cgi and the 2nd is test.cgi. It is giving the internal error. I wrote the simple code into it and url is http://mts.marketsignalsoftware.com/cgi-bin/test.cgi.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w
 # Program to do the obvious
 print 'Hello world.';      
 # Print a message
```

Thanks

Comment: check the error log. If you aren't doing that then you aren't doing your job and anything else is just guessing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check your error logs and you will see a message about missing headers, maybe something like `Premature end of script headers ...`.
The first output of a CGI script should always be a content type header.

Try

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
print 'Hello world.';
```

Obligatory trouble shooting link for the next problem you have:

[How can I troubleshoot my Perl CGI script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165022/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-perl-cgi-script)

Comment: showing the following warning in the error log.                   [Tue Jan 10 13:23:54 2012] [error] [client 122.173.44.138] (13)Permission denied: exec of '/mnt/stor10-wc2-dfw1/577993/mts.marketsignalsoftware.com/web/cgi-bin/test.cgi' failed
[Tue Jan 10 13:23:54 2012] [error] [client 122.173.44.138] Premature end of script headers: test.cgiwing the following warning in error log.

Comment: @Rohit Sharma - see [the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165022/). There are 29 other things you can try.

Comment: Permission denied -> Make sure `/mnt/stor10-wc2-dfw1/577993/mts.marketsignalsoftware.com/web/cgi-bin/test.cgi` is reachable and executable by the user as which the web server executes. That means each parent directory (`.../cgi-bin`, `.../web`, etc) must also be reachable by the user as which the web server executes.