# executing perl cgi script from html

Tags: html, perl

I'm, trying to run a perl script from html, but I'm getting error during execution. Here is  my html and 2 lines perl code. The error code is not very descriptive just says "Internal Server Error" and some other lines. I also want to know how to display the receive user name in the perl script.

```
pwd
/var/www/cgi-bin

ls -l
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 49 Aug 26 16:49 username.pl
```

Html Code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Hello </h1>
<form action="/cgi-bin/username.pl" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="username">
     <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Received user name is\n";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Internal Server Error when the perl code run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809131/internal-server-error-when-the-perl-code-run)

Comment: What web server are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Perl script is not generating appropriate CGI headers. Please read [`perldoc CGI`](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html), or, for a quick answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new();
my $username = $q->param("username");
print $q->header(-type => "text/plain");
print "Received username is $username\n";
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you also explain just a little bit lines wit "my" in them?

Comment: Read the documentation I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

1>.my declares the listed variables to be local to the enclosing block, file.

2>.if you have a text box name user in your html page

i.e. something like this:-

```
<td><b><font color="green" size="3">USER</font><input type="text" name="user" value="">
```

then try this

```
my $user=$query->param("user");
```

in your cgi script and get the input in the variable $user.