# basic help for Perl CGI module

Tags: perl, cgi

I want to use the Perl CGI module for creating CGI scripts. I went through the documentation available 
[here](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html) but I seem to have missed something obvious because I have 
run into problems with my first program. Here is the HTML:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="http://localhost/cgi-bin/filters.cgi">
<input name="mainbox" type="checkbox"> Mainbox<br> <br>
<input name="n1" type="checkbox">No. 1 <br><br>
<input name="n2" type="checkbox"> No. 2<br><br>
<input name="n3" type="checkbox">No. 3 <br>
<div style="text-align: center;"><input name="Submit" value="Submit" type="submit"></div>
</form>
```

I simply want the names of the parameters that are passed to the CGI file to be printed on a new 
page. So (with my limited understanding), I wrote the following in filters.cgi:

```
#!/xampp/perl/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $query = CGI->new;
print $query = $query->header('text/html');
my @names = $query->param;

my $q1 = CGI->new;
print $q1->header('text/html');
print $q1->start_html('hello');
foreach my $name (@names) {
    print $q1->h1($name);
}
print $q1->end_html;
```

But this prints out nothing. It does not give me any error either and the syntax is OK.
I know I am missing something very simple here but I really want some help with this. How do
I write this script correctly? I am using XAMPP in Windows XP, if that makes any difference.

EDIT: Maybe I should mention that I have tried to figure this out myself. So I wrote the 
following script which works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my @arr = ('ac', 'fg', 'ty');
my $q1 = CGI->new;
print $q1->header('text/html');
$q1->start_html('hello world');
foreach my $el (@arr) {
    print $q1->p($el);
}
$q1->end_html;
```

So the problem is somewhere in the parameters being passed. I don't even know where to look for 
help in the long documentation, so decided to ask here. Also, I have seen the link Nikhil 
has posted in the comments. One of the points mentioned there is that I should try running my 
script from the command line. How do I pass these parameters from the command line?

Comment: see [How can I troubleshoot my Perl CGI script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165022/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-perl-cgi-script)?

Comment: @NikhilJain thanks for the link, but I had already gone through it earlier. Could you be more specific as to which of those suggestions could apply to my case? Please see my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first issue you had was that you were assigning the result of calling `$query->header('text/html')` back into your `$query` variable, destroying the query object which meant that the next line `my @names = $query->param` wasn't working as expected.

Secondly, you were attempting to print the `Content-type` header twice, once using the `$query` CGI object and once using the `$q1` object.

I have removed the unnecessary CGI object, `$q1`, and used the original `$query` object in all cases.

The following is the code with the above fixes applied.

```
#!/xampp/perl/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $query = CGI->new;
my @names = $query->param;

print $query->header('text/html');
print $query->start_html('hello');

foreach my $name (@names) {
    print $query->h1($name);
}

print $query->end_html;
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I overlooked this earlier!

Answer (score 2):

```
print $query = $query->header('text/html');
```

This line is part of your problem. `$query->header()` returns some text, which isn't a useful value to set `$query` to. You're also creating two `CGI` objects (`$query` and `$q1`) where you only need one, and printing two sets of headers. Get rid of the duplication and the inappropriate assignment, and you should be fine.

Comment: What should I set $query to, instead of 'text/html'?