# CGI Perl script and Monkey web server on Damn Small Linux

Tags: linux, perl, web, cgi

I need small virtual machine with a Web server, so I decided to install Damn Small Linux. I need to run a Web server that is hosting a site with a script that checks for a server's IP address and returns it in a HTML page. So far I have something like this working:

Script file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n" ;
print <<EOF ;
<html>
<head><title>CGI Results</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Hello, world.</h1>
</body>
</html>
EOF
exit ;
```

The script is called from HTML like this:

```
<iframe src="http://localhost/cgi-bin/skrypt.cgi" width="100%"></iframe>
```

It's working fine, but whenever I add something to this script other than a `print` statement, for example:

```
my $address = "someValue"
```

… then the HTML page is not running the script but instead it is downloading it. What do I have to do to make this script work? I just need an IP address to appear on the Web page.

Comment: _Downloading it_ may be a matter of web server configuration instead. What webserver are you using? Does it need to be configured to not allow downloading of `cgi-bin/` content?

Comment: From the [Stack Overflow Perl FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=faq): [How can I troubleshoot my Perl CGI script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165022/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-perl-cgi-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run your cgi script in the command line:

```
perl -c my_script.cgi
```

and if it is ok, try to run using strict and warnings activated.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
```

If there is no problem, look into the error log.

Comment: I used perl -c my_script.cgi command and it found some bugs. Thank you very much!