# Uploading file through perl CGI script

Tags: perl, apache, file-upload, cgi

I am trying to upload a file on localhost server (Apache 2.2 on Linux platform), but I am getting **Internal Server Error 500**.

Server is running fine (as I am able to print all environment variables through CGI script), I am unable to find my way even after lot of googling.

This is my HTML code:

```
<FORM ACTION="http://localhost/cgi-bin/upload.cgi" METHOD="post" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
<INPUT TYPE="file" NAME="photo">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="Submit" VALUE="Submit Form">
</FORM>
```

This is my cgi script that is being placed at /var/www/cgi-bin where I have given full permission to this file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI;

$upload_dir = "/home/myuser/Desktop/upload";
$query = new CGI;
$filename = $query->param("photo");
$filename =~ s/.*[\/\\](.*)/$1/;
$upload_filehandle = $query->upload("photo");

open UPLOADFILE, ">$upload_dir/$filename";
while ( <$upload_filehandle> )
{
print UPLOADFILE;
}
close UPLOADFILE;

print $query->header ();

print <<END_HTML;
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Thanks!</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<P>Thanks for uploading your photo!</P>
    <P>Your photo:</P>
<img src="/home/myuser/Desktop/upload/$filename" border="0">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Please somebody provide me a hint to solve the above simple problem. Thanks.

Comment: From the [Stack Overflow Perl FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=faq): [How can I troubleshoot my Perl CGI script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165022/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-perl-cgi-script)

Answer (score 0):

Check the apache error log (often found in /var/log/httpd/error_log) for warnings or error messages. I suspect that the problem is that the upload directory is not [writable](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2008/12/09/making-a-directory-writable-by-the-webserver/) by the web server.

Answer (score 0):

**print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";**
This is a content-type header that tells the receiving web browser what sort of data it is about to receive — in this case, an HTML document. If you forget to include it, or if you print something else before printing this header, you'll get an **"Internal Server Error"** when you try to access the CGI program.

END_HTML is also missing at the EOF.

Comment: To see what error occurs, check your apache error log. Depending on installation it may be in `/var/log/apache2/`