# 500 Internal Server Error in perl-cgi program

Tags: forms, perl, cgi, internal-server-error, cgi-bin

I am getting error as "Internal Server Error.The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

I am submitting a form in html and get its values.

HTML Code (index.cgi)

```
#!c:/perl/bin/perl.exe
print "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n\n";
print "<html>";
print "<body>";
print "<form name = 'login' method = 'get' action = '/cgi-bin/login.pl'> <input type = 'text' name = 'uid'><br /><input type = 'text' name = 'pass'><br /><input type = 'submit'>";
print "</body>";
print "</html>";
```

Perl Code to fetch data (login.pl)

```
#!c:/perl/bin/perl.exe
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
my(%frmfields);
getdata(\%frmfields);
sub getdata {
    my ($buffer) = "";
    if (($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq 'GET')) {
        my (%hashref) = shift;
        $buffer = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
        foreach  (split(/&/,$buffer)) {
            my ($key, $value) = split(/=/, $_);
            $key = decodeURL($key);
            $value= decodeURL($value);
            $hashref{$key} = $value;
        }
    }
    else{
        read(STDIN,$buffer,$ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'})
    }
}

sub decodeURL{
    $_=shift;
    tr/+/ /;
    s/%(..)/pack('c', hex($1))/eg;
    return($_);
}
```

The HTML page opens correctly but when i submit the form, i get internal server error.

Please help.

Comment: it might be worth writing a separate Perl script to setup $ENV with some hardcoded, reasonable values, and use it to test your getdata sub -- that way, you'd probably get some more helpful debugging info.

Comment: Also, don't write your own query string parser, use [CGI.pm](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html) instead.

Comment: Obligatory [How can I troubleshoot my Perl-CGI script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165022/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-perl-cgi-script)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What does the web server's error log say?

Independent of what it says, you *must* stop parsing the form data yourself. There are modules for that, specifically [CGI.pm](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI). Using that, you can do this instead:

```perl
use CGI;

my $CGI = CGI->new();

my $uid  = $CGI->param( 'uid'  );
my $pass = $CGI->param( 'pass' );

# rest of your script
```

Much cleaner and much safer.

Comment: This works for me.. Also I simply added a header line : print $CGI->header('text/html');    And now its working. Thanks Tore

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Tore that you must not parse this yourself. Your code has multiple errors. You don't allow multiple parameter values, you don't allow the ; alternate separator, you don't handle POST with a query string in the URL, and so on.

I don't know how long it will be online for free, but [chapter 15 of my new "Beginning Perl" book covers Web programming](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781118013847/the_interwebs.html). That should get you started on some decent basics. Note that the online version is an early, rough draft. The actual book also includes Chapter 19 which has a complete Web app example.

Answer (score 1):

could it be this line that's the problem?

```
my (%hashref) = shift;
```

You're initialising a proper hash, but `shift` will give you a hash reference, since you did `getdata(\%frmfields);`. You probably want this, instead:

```
my $hashref = shift;
```

Answer (score 1):

"500 Internal Server Error" just means that something didn't work the way the web server expected.  Maybe you don't have CGI enabled.  Maybe the script isn't executable.  Maybe it's in a directory the web server isn't allowed to access.  It's even possible that maybe the web server ran the script successfully and it worked *perfectly*, but didn't start its output with a valid set of HTTP headers.  You need to look in the web server's error log to find out what it didn't like, which may or may not be a Perl issue.

Like everyone else has said, though, don't try to parse query strings and grovel though `%ENV` yourself.  Use one of the many fine modules or frameworks which are available and already known to work correctly.  [CGI.pm](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI) is the granddaddy of them all and works well for smaller projects, but I'd recommend looking into a proper web application framework such as [Dancer](https://metacpan.org/module/Dancer), [Mojolicious](https://metacpan.org/module/Mojolicious), or [Catalyst](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst) (there are many others, but those are the big three) if you're planning to build anything with more than a handful of relatively simple pages and forms.

Comment: How can i check the error log? where is it placed? i am using apache 2 server