# Website Perl Script fails with json module

Tags: json, perl, cgi

I want to run a [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) script which uses JSON on my website. I've tested the following script in the cgi-bin folder with success:

```perl
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

print "Content-Type: text/html \n\n";
print "<h1 align=center>\n";
print "Welcome to my website\n";
print "</h1>\n";
```

But as soon as I include the JSON module, the website's CMS (OpenCart) reverts to a "Page cannot be found" error:

```perl
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use JSON;

print "Content-Type: text/html \n\n";
print "<h1 align=center>\n";
print "Welcome to my website\n";
print "</h1>\n";
```

A rep from the website host confirmed JSON is installed on the (linux) server

Am I using the correct syntax to include JSON in my script?

Comment: Can you find the CMS logs and see what the exact error from Perl was? That, or simply run your script on command line

Comment: Also, check if you have JSON or JSON::PP installed (the latter was in the core Perl since 5.14): `perl -MJSON -e ''` and `perl -MJSON::PP -e ''`

Comment: obligatory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165022/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-perl-cgi-script

Comment: @DVK Couldn't find any logs related to the Perl script in my cgi-bin folder, but thanks for your second comment, that helped me solve this.

Comment: @mob I went through the valuable link, thanks, will be sure to pass it along

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DVK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119280/dvk) commented:

> Also, check if you have JSON or JSON::PP installed (the latter was in
>   the core Perl since 5.14): `perl -MJSON -e ''`and `perl -MJSON::PP -e ''`

Thanks DVK, if I include `use JSON::PP` instead of `use JSON`, the [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) script works.

I had to change some JSON-specific functions to JSON::PP functions (ie. change `$json->objToJson` to `$json->encode`) for it to work with JSON::PP.

[This link](http://www.dispersiondesign.com/articles/perl/json_data) also provided some help