# "End of script output before headers" - CGI on Apache

Tags: apache, perl, cgi

I have the following CGI script:

```
#!c:\cygwin\bin\perl.exe

use CGI qw(:standard);

my $query = $CGI->new;

print header (
  -type   => "text/html",
  -status => "404 File not found"
);

print "<b>File not found</b>";
```

This gives me an error:

```
Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message:
End of script output before headers: test.cgi

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 500
127.0.0.1
Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1h PHP/5.4.31
```

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307610/end-of-script-output-before-headers-error-in-apache) (and other similar) question(s), but there the headers were not being `print`ed, as opposed to mine.

I'm using the XAMPP Windows package with Cygwin Perl.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Internal server errors mean you should read the server logs, where you can see the error message perl is outputting before it dies.

Comment: You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program you write. This applies especially if you are asking others for help with your code, as it is a very simple first debugging step. In this case you would have seen the message `Global symbol "$CGI" requires explicit package name` which is precisely the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you are using **$CGI** instead of **CGI**

I think It should be

```
my $query = CGI->new;
```

tested on Linux working perfect.

Answer (score 2):

So, as others have pointed out, your problem was using a variable (`$CGI`) where you actually needed a class name (`CGI`). But, in my mind, this raises two more questions.

1/ Why are you trying to create a CGI object in the first place? You are using the function-based interface to CGI (`print header(...)` for example) so there's no need for a CGI object.

2/ Why are you writing a CGI program in 2014? Perl web programming has moved on a long way this millennium and you seem to be stuck in the 1990s :-/