# "End of script output before headers" on CentOS, but working on other LAMP stacks

Tags: php, apache, centos, cpanel

I've set up a Centos 6 + CPanel 11 VPS, and everything is as it was out of the box. I've installed Phorum 5.2.20 in the public_html directory, but Phorum is causing an error 500. The error log reports:

[Mon Jul 27 11:21:57.770447 2015] [core:error] [pid 14342] [client x.x.x.x:42531] End of script output before headers: admin.php

The code works fine on my Debian LAMP server (and several other non-Centos/CPanel LAMP stacks I've used to test this), and Wordpress and some other stuff runs fine on the CentOS machine.

I've tried other code too, and it works on my other servers, but doesn't work on CentOS.  Phorum is the only code that matters, so I made question focuses on that. I'm also reluctant to edit the core files of Phorum.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307610/end-of-script-output-before-headers-error-in-apache

Comment: Other comment it's a paintfull response. Question it's about php not perl issue.

Comment: Please put a file named example info.php with this code <?php infophp(); ?> and analized result.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed: Permission Issue

I have also faced the same issue after installing fresh installation on VPS, later I found It's a permission issue, Directory should be 755 and files should be 644 then only it works.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 projectfolder
sudo chmod -R 644 index.php //projectfiles
```

Comment: Correct, and use "ls-l" to check the owner of the files, if not correct then use chown to correct them

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an issues with the php handler. Can you please try to change your php handler through WHM >>Service Configuration >> Configure PHP and suEXEC and check your URL again.

Answer (score 1):

For me the error was caused by file permissions. Luckily it was just the one file causing it so I used the same permissions as the working .php files and it worked.

In my case 644 worked with enough permission to run and not too much to trip the security settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error for more than a day finally i found out that accidentally my `/home/mysite_username/fcgi-bin/php7.0.fcgi` file `owner` and `group` was changed to `root`. Restoring owner to `mysite_username` solved this issue. (I'm using Virtualmin)

Answer (score 0):

Fix permissions from User Account Menu of CWP.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! be honest now, you thought you were being concise with this one, right? The thing is, you could have made this a comment and be done with it. I know, I know, not enough reps, been there. My advice, elaborate better answers and post good questions so you rep up and are able to comment in the future. [Best of lucks!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)