# I Could not host my Laravel App on server?

Tags: php, laravel, centos, web-hosting, http-status-code-500

i hope you can help me with that stuff

so i completed a client's laravel app and tried to host it on the client's server but it was not working , it was showing the error

```
End of script output before headers: index.php
```

i hope you help me solve the problem

Server is Runing on CentosLinux Os:

```
Apache v : 2.4
php v : 7.2
Mysql v :10.1
```

My Application is Built on : Laravel Framework v7.2

Comment: Maybe is a permission issue.. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651744/end-of-script-output-before-headers-on-centos-but-working-on-other-lamp-stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651744/end-of-script-output-before-headers-on-centos-but-working-on-other-lamp-stack)

Comment: i've already changed the permissions to 644 for php files inside the public_html directory & to 755 for the app folder inside the home directory 
but it seems likes nothing was changed , any idea?

Comment: it seems likes it has a problem with reading php files , i tried to update the index file extenstion to be html and it was read as html normally

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 7 needs php >= 7.2.5

Take a look to the server requirements in [Laravel 7 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x)