# Internal Server Error End of script before Headers C cgi files

Tags: c, apache, cgi

Thanks in advance for the help, I apologize if this isn't the right area for this. I'm trying to get a website ported from Raspbian Wheezy to Raspbian Jessie, I think that I have the apache.conf and default.conf configured correctly as it loads the index page. The index page is a very short html file that redirects to a CGI file, the cgi file is located in /var/www/cgi-bin/ along with all the other cgi files for the website (the entire site is cgi files). The problem that I'm running into is that the inital cgi file executes and loads just fine, the remainder of the cgi files result in a 500 Internal server error. When I check the Apache error.log file and it was giving the ever helpful "end of script before headers" error. I can only figure that it's something to do with the new OS which is a fresh install, vs the old version which configured and setup before I started working on the site, with no documentation that I can find. What's getting me (and maybe I can't see the forest for the trees) is that one of the cgi files runs and the rest fail. I've checked ownership, permissions, location, apache 2.4 configuration vs the 2.2 that it's getting ported from, and a few other things that are escaping me at the moment. I'll try to provide what I can but it's not much.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307610/end-of-script-output-before-headers-error-in-apache

Comment: I've tried most of what is being suggested there, other than selinux, as I'm sure it's not installed on my system, seeing as how the package doesn't appear when i use `dpkg --get-selections | less'. The permissions are 755,  and on our other deployments the owner doesn't matter.

Comment: Have you read this from the RPI site? https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/apache.md    It notes the defatult web page directory has changed on JESSIE to /var/www/html        from /var/www on Wheezy.  Perhaps there has been another change for the CGI directory.

Comment: I did take a look over that page, I'm not seeing anything about theCGI directory, and my CGI Directory isn't the standard location (/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/) vs mine at /var/www/cgi-bin/ the thing being is that the initail cgi script for the login page works and the rest fail on Jessis, Where on Wheezy they all work as expected.