# Execute python using wamp server windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache, wamp, cgi

I'm using WAMP server and i have configured it to run python scripts and those scripts are executing but i was trying to run below script, this script is executing in windows terminal but when i try to execute it from browser with the help of wamp server then i'm getting this error :

> Apache error log :

```
[Sat Nov 27 11:12:01.808031 2021] [cgi:error] [pid 6040:tid 1220] [client ::1:56483] End of script output before headers: test_nm.py
```

> Apache access log :

```
::1 - - [27/Nov/2021:11:11:57 +0530] "-" 408 -
::1 - - [27/Nov/2021:11:12:01 +0530] "GET /test_nm.py HTTP/1.1" 500 653
```

> Code

```
#!C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe

print("Content-Type: text/html\n")

import numpy as np
import wave
from deepspeech import Model
from scipy.io import wavfile as wav
#import speech_recognition as sr

audio_file = "C:/deepspeechwk/audio/8455-210777-0068.wav"
ds = Model('C:/deepspeechwk/deepspeech-0.6.0-models/output_graph.pb',500)
ds.enableDecoderWithLM('C:/deepspeechwk/deepspeech-0.6.0-models/lm.binary','C:/deepspeechwk/deepspeech-0.6.0-models/trie', 0.75, 1.85)
rate, audio = wav.read(audio_file)
print(audio)
transcript =ds.stt(audio)
#print(transcript)

f = open("transcribe_text.txt", "a")
f.write(str(transcript))
f.close()
```

Screenshot :

[image]

Any solution to resolve this issue is highly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: It seems that somehow printing the header is incorrect according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22308061/7828101 . Does `print("Content-Type: text/html\n")` works for all your other python scripts? Does remove all but the imports give the same exception ?

Comment: @manaclan: When i remove import then there is no error. print("Content-Type: text/html\n") is working in other scripts

Comment: you should try comment out each line to narrow down the problem and post it here. I can't help much as I don't have your code

Comment: @manaclan In my question i have added the code

Comment: I mean, try comment all your code and then uncomment each line until the program break. Update the line that cause the program to break onto your question

Comment: @manaclan when i remove these imports `import wave from deepspeech import Model
from scipy.io import wavfile as wav` then there is no error, but i have to import these to run my code

Comment: did you install those library

Comment: @manaclan yes i have installed these library and it is working when i run same program from the python terminal, issue is when i run in browser