# Debug CGI script that does not print HTML

Tags: perl, cgi

I would like to know how to debug a `cgi` script that doesn't output any `HTML`.

I currently have a login page with a `html` form that upon submission redirects to another `cgi` script. This script is supposed to check whether the user has inputted correct information.

This script does not print out any `html` so I'm not sure how I am supposed to check it. I am currently receiving an `Internal Server Error`  when the redirection occurs to this script.
The `error.log` states:

```
End of script output before headers:
```

Could someone please tell me a way I can debug this script?

Thank you for your help.

`main.cgi`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use CGI qw/:all/;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser);
use CGI::Cookie;
use Data::Dumper;  
use List::Util qw/min max/;
warningsToBrowser(1);

# print start of HTML ASAP to assist debugging if there is an error in the script
print page_header();

# Get Cookies
%cookies = CGI::Cookie->fetch;

# If no cookie, display login page
if (!%cookies){
   # Redirects the user to login.cgi
   print show_login_form();
}

#if cookie
#  do something

print page_trailer();
```

`login.cgi`

```
use CGI qw/:all/;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser);
use CGI::Cookie;
use Data::Dumper;  
use List::Util qw/min max/;
warningsToBrowser(1);

$cookie_value = "";



# Convert request method to Uppercase eg: GET, POST
$ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;

# If "POST" request sent, check login credentials
if ("$ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'}" eq "POST"){
   # Get login parameters
   $username = param('username');   
   $password = param('password');   

   $loginCheckResult = check_login($username, $password);

   # If login was successful, create a cookie
   if ($loginCheckResult){
       # Set Cookie
       $cookie = CGI::Cookie->new(-name=>$cookie_value,-value=>$cookie_value);      


   # If login was Unsuccessful, redisplay the login page
   } else {
    # Do something here...  
   }
}
```

Comment: Please post your script. Are you aware you can write log messages to help debug a script?

Comment: @ialarmedalien Thanks for your response. No I didn't know that.

Comment: Please edit your scripts to `use strict; use warnings;` so you get error messages from Perl.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I troubleshoot my Perl CGI script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165022/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-perl-cgi-script)

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#CREATING-A-STANDARD-HTTP-HEADER%3a

Comment: Thanks @mpapec @ialarmedalien. I'm very new to `CGI` so quite lost with a lot of things..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `End of script output before headers:` means your script finished without outputting anything. Essentially, you've created a `CGI::Cookie` but not [sent it to the browser](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI/Cookie.html#Sending-the-Cookie-to-the-Browser):

```
$cookie->bake;
```

If you wanted to set the cookie and then redirect to another page, you could use:

```
print redirect(-uri => 'other_page.html', -cookie => $cookie);
```

Comment: Thanks RobEarl. I fixed this up. I noticed that I didn't need to add`$cookie->bake`. It didn't seem to work when I added that line. I also read the following: `The redirect() function redirects the browser to a different URL. If you use redirection like this, you should not print out a header as well.` (source: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=695252)

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem, used a simple cgi hello world as following 0end6.cgi

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html><body><h1>Hello World!";
print "</h1></body></html>\n";
```

I got error both on browser and error log as AH01264

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30186745)