# LAMPP - CGI-Script not working

Tags: perl, cgi, lampp

## Hello

I have got a LAMPP Webserver. I tried to open a CGI Script called "Hello.cgi".

It contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Hello World.\n";
```

The path is: /opt/lampp/htdocs/dashboard/cgi-bin/hello.cgi

When I open: "127.0.0.1/dashboard/cgi-bin/hello.cgi", I get following:

> Server error!
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Error message:
>   End of script output before headers: hello.cgi
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

The CGI Script is written in Perl.

If you need more informations about my problem, say it, please.

~~runasas

Comment: There are basically 100 different things that could be wrong. Did you check the server log? Have you tried running the script from the command line? Are you sending any HTTP headers?

Comment: @MattJacob I ran it in the command line now, it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, but... that just confirms that there's nothing wrong with the script itself.

Comment: When it's not the script, then it's the server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165022/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-perl-cgi-script

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should never write a Perl program without including the lines `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.

Secondly, if you have problems with a CGI program, you should check the web server error log for more details of the problem.

Thirdly, the output from a CGI program needs to include a content type header. So you'll want to add the following:

```
print "Content-Type: text/plain\015\012\015\012";
```

This becomes easier if you use the [CGI module](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI):

```
use CGI;
print header('text/plain');
```

But really, in 2016, you shouldn't be writing CGI programs - there are [plenty of good alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) available.